# What are the parameters for using \item{$\bullet$}

Tags: enumitem

I get the following error using TeXstudio

> Lonely \item--perhaps a missing list environment. \item{

whenever `\item{$\bullet$} text` is used

See example below

The document(s) that I am taking this from hundreds of these one line items with no begin statement.

**Question**
If the begin{itemize} is required can it be declared once for the whole document ?

---

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{listings}

\usepackage{enumitem}


% This begins the document:
\begin{document}


% This line effectively turns off "Underfull \vbox" and "Underfull \hbox" error messages.
\hbadness=20000
\vbadness=20000

\tolerance = 1000
\pretolerance = 10000



% Define "pseudocode" as a language recognized by the "listings" package:
\lstdefinelanguage{pseudocode}
{morekeywords={DECLARE,BEGIN,END,LOOP,ENDLOOP,SET,IF,THEN,CALL,RETURN,ELSEIF,ELSE,ENDIF,PRINT,OUTPUT,AND,OR},
 morecomment=[l]{//}
}

\lstloadlanguages{pseudocode,[ANSI]C}



% This item list works fine
\begin{itemize}

    \item Version 1.1 -- released April 16, 2017 for public use 

\end{itemize}


%This is the type of list structure that I need using TeXstudio

\item{$\bullet$} Insert bullet text here



%% The end! %%

\end{document}

\end{book}
```

Comment: your question doesn't really have a question?? the command `\item` is a syntax error if not used in a list. So you are showing a syntax error but not saying what output you want.

Comment: why `\pretolerance = 10000` ?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I'm assuming he wants an itemization, but with `$\bullet$` as a fixed symbol.... something like `\begin{itemize}[label=$\bullet$] \item Bullet text \item Next Bullet text \end{itemize}`.

Comment: @BMWurm I might have guessed that, if that wasn't effectively the default for itemize already!

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Yeah, that struck me as odd, too -- then I thought this all looks a bit like a pre-existing template being filled out, so maybe he is just stating what he wants without having a deeper understanding of environments and their use....

Comment: Yes this is an existing template, however the begin document and usepackage statements are not included. I'm new to latex and trying to piece this together.

Comment: while it is possible to redefine _everything_ in latex it really isn't a good idea. `\item` not in a list is a syntax error so it is better to fix the input than go in to latex internals and redefine the syntax.

Comment: are you sure that your template using `\item` is for _latex_ and not for _plain tex_ (which has a command of that name with the syntax you are using)

Comment: The original file is http://www.ibiblio.org/kuphaldt/socratic/sinst/sinst.tar.gz

Comment: This is a huge archive that involves unix bash scripts used to assemble the tex documents. I'm trying to make my own worksheets (assembling by hand) but the document preamble.tex appears to be messing begin{document} and other necessary formating instructions. There is build.txt guide included. I've spent 3 days trying to get this to work but I'm thinking that converting the pdf to doc and then grabbing the content that I need may be easier. I have enjoyed using latex though and I was able to build my own text with selected chapters using latex. Thank you for your help.

Comment: er no 523M compressed I think I won't look:-)

Comment: Yeah for a first time latex project this was a good one.

Comment: I think the original author had the entire document as one big list with no default bullet. I added \renewcommand{\labelitemi}{}

and inserted the entire text in between \begin{itemize} and \end{itemize}. which seemed to work. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

Really changing latex syntax will bite you in the end, but as you may not want to edit a few hundred megabytes of tex written by someone else....

It is in fact simple to make the default `\item` be ignored rather than make an error.

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{listings}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\renewcommand\makelabel[1]{}% silence lonely item error

% This begins the document:
\begin{document}


% This line effectively turns off "Underfull \vbox" and "Underfull \hbox" error messages.
% please don't !
%\hbadness=20000
%\vbadness=20000

%\tolerance = 1000
%\pretolerance = 10000



% Define "pseudocode" as a language recognized by the "listings" package:
\lstdefinelanguage{pseudocode}
{morekeywords={DECLARE,BEGIN,END,LOOP,ENDLOOP,SET,IF,THEN,CALL,RETURN,ELSEIF,ELSE,ENDIF,PRINT,OUTPUT,AND,OR},
 morecomment=[l]{//}
}

\lstloadlanguages{pseudocode,[ANSI]C}



% This item list works fine
\begin{itemize}

    \item Version 1.1 -- released April 16, 2017 for public use 

\end{itemize}


%This is the type of list structure that I need using TeXstudio

\item{$\bullet$} Insert bullet text here



%% The end! %%

\end{document}

\end{book}
```